# DOM manipulation performance when toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have bunch of images in a wrapper div. I need to hide all of them except the one user clicks on.
What is the most performance concise way of doing that? 
Should I apply class on all of them to hide them all and than filter out the one that was clicked and show only that one or should I loop over them all hiding them as loop progresses with exception of the one that was clicked or something else?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern desktop browsers you won't see any difference. Browsers are tuned so that they are blazing fast in rendering any changes is DOM three. Guts tell me that it might be  sligtly faster to loop through all images and set visibility depending on item clicked using style attribute and not using class. In that way you have to process only N elements and no external CSS files are involved. If you hide all and show the element with was clicked, you process N + 1 elements.

In your situation I would use solution that is fastest, more managable and clean from the developers standpoint as there won't be much difference in the final result if you use one method or another.

Comment: But doesn't looping over elements and giving every one except the one that was clicked style attribute means that i make as much trips to Dom as there are elements in loop to process? Or this operation has nothing to do with dom?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most performant ways would be to let CSS do the visibility. It sounds to me like you're only displaying one at a time, in which case you can do it with two DOM operations by using classes;

```
// scope above
var lastClicked = null;

// then  in click listener, 1st param `e`
if (lastClicked) lastClicked.className = ''; // remove visible class
lastClicked = e.target; // get clicked node
lastClicked.className = 'visible'; // add visible class
```

I'm assuming [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) but depending how the listener is attached, you might want to use `this` or some other logic. Further, if you expect [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) support, you can use `add` and `remove` from that.

---

Example CSS of how to show only nodes with class token `visible`.

```
selector:not(.visible) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to be correct. You set class 'visible' to clicked element, but what happens to other elements? They will still be visible as no manipulation on their class is done. Yous should be attaching class 'hide' to other elements instead of attaching class 'visible' to the clicked element.

Comment: @KasparsOzols I hope my edit to include some example CSS shows how you only need one flag for this

Comment: In that case you would need to assign class 'visible' for every item in list on page load so you have something to click on. If you do that, then your initial code still would not hide other items...

Comment: @KasparsOzols if it is run-once code, the CSS can be injected after the click instead of removing a prior visibility flag.

Comment: Gee, you are taking this too personal. I am not saying that it is imposible to do what you suggested, I am saying that it is counter-intuitive and adding class 'hide' would be much easier solution.

Comment: I will try this out too. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

PS: If you're using jquery, you can use the following:

Lets say, your div has id='test-div', and there are several images in it. All these images can be accessed as:

```
$('#test-div img')
```

Now, lets assume you know the id of image which got clicked. Lets assume id='my-image'.

You can execute the following to hide all other images (except 'my-image'):

```
$('#test-div img').not('#my-image').addClass('hide')
```

Comment: You can exclude DOM element from result directly using JQuery code like this:

`$('#test-div img').not(clickedElement).addClass('hide')`

Comment: Sweet. Is there anything jQuery can't do? :)
Maybe i will use it after all.